# Rake file task with 100s of files

Tags: rake, rake-task

I'm just now learning about file tasks in Rake.  I have 100s of javascript source files, that get concatenated to 10 or so files.  I see this kind of mapping can be done intelligently with file tasks.  It appears you need to specify every file.

Is there an efficient way to write a file task that recursively finds all of these javascript files and compare them to the concatenated files on the right side?  The concatenation part is a tricky step and is being done by a custom build tool at the moment until I can get that in ruby.

For example,

```
/a.js
/c.js            -----------> base.js
/geo/b.js
/geo/c.js        -----------> geo.js
/mod/d.js
/mod/e.js        -----------> mod.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file 'base.js' => Dir['*.js'] do |t|
  concatenate t.prerequisites, t.name
end

file 'geo.js' => Dir['geo/*.js'] do |t|
  concatenate t.prerequisites, t.name
end
```

and so on, you will have to implement the `concatenate` method yourself, obviously (in my example the first argument is the list of files and the second is the destination file, e.g. `geo.js`). If all created files are named after directories you can do something like this:

```
%w(geo mod xyz abc).each do |module|
  file "#{module}.js" => Dir["#{module}/*.js"] do |t|
    concatenate t.prerequisites, t.name
  end
end
```

If the directories can be globbed somehow you could make it even more dynamic by replacing the list of directory names with `Dir[...]` too.

Comment: I started to realize it was unfeasible for it to check a..n module files against a..z source files.  I was hoping to be able to write this without specifying every target file and every source file... some sort of mapping.

Answer (score 0):

How to invoke this rake file task?

```
%w(geo mod xyz abc).each do |module|
  file "#{module}.js" => Dir["#{module}/*.js"] do |t|
    # some code
  end
end
```

> > rake ????

Comment: Add `task :everything => "#{module}.js"` below the `file` task definition (just before the last end). Then you can run all with `rake everything`.